# Seeking advice for case switch in loops. my description is below

Tags: java

How do I make my output for Binary to Decimal this: Choice: 1 Binary Number : 2222 INVALID Binary Number

If a user types the binary above 1.

Also, how should I make the default of the switch case not show unless the user inputs the wrong option. Example: They input "HOOPdoop" which is not on the menu screen, the default will output saying that they must try again with the correct input. However, I don't want the default to output when the user inputs "Octal to Decimal" / after the calculation.

here is my code:

````
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //VARIABLES BEFOR LOOP / FOR LOOP
        boolean Loop = true;
        String Choice;
        //OBJECTS
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (Loop == true) {
            //MENU
            System.out.println("This program will convert...\n" + " \n" + "Binary to Decimal\n" + "Octal to Decimal\n" + "Decimal to Binary\n" + "Decimal to Octal\n" + "or you may Exit");
            //ASK
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Which converter would you like to use? or would you like to exit? : ");
            Choice = input.nextLine();
            //VARIABLES INSIDE LOOP
            String binary = "";
            int decimal;
            String octal;
            switch (Choice) {
                case "Binary to Decimal":
                    System.out.print("Enter a binary number: ");
                    binary = input.nextLine();
                    if (binary.equals(2)) {
                        System.out.println("INVALID.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Decimal: " + Integer.parseInt(binary, 2));
                        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Decimal to Binary":
                    System.out.print("Enter decimal number: ");
                    decimal = input.nextInt();
                    int answer = decimal;
                    while (answer > 0) {
                        binary = (answer % 2) + binary;
                        answer = answer / 2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The binary number = " + binary);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;
                case "Decimal to Octal":
                    System.out.print("Enter decimal number: ");
                    decimal = input.nextInt();
                    octal = Integer.toOctalString(decimal);
                    System.out.println("Octal number = " + octal);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;
                case "Octal to Decimal":
                    System.out.print("Enter a Octal number: ");
                    octal = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Decimal: " + Integer.parseInt(octal, 8));
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;
                case "Exit":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!!");
                    Loop = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Note: You can't compare a string to a number. Comparing `binary` to `2` will always return `false`. You have to use `String` operations or a regular expression to check if the string is an invalid binary - or use the exception thrown by `parseInt`.

Comment: Side note: Do not let variable names begin with an uppercase (`Loop`, `Choice`). They should start with a lowercase to avoid confusions with class names (which start in uppercase).

Comment: @RealSkeptic  I'm new to Computer Science so I don't really know what you mean. Could you please give me an example? Thank you! (: